# Help with sound for a Xbox 360 w/ HDMI cable

Tags: xbox-360

I just got the new "kinect ready" 4GB Xbox 360 and I have it hooked up to my computer monitor via an HDMI cable (no actual TV). However my monitor has no built in speakers, hence no sound. Looking at the back of the xbox it looks like the only way I can get sound is to try and run a SPDIF-to-RCA converter from the xbox into my audio mixer.

The AUX cable that comes with it has the RCA connections on it, but its got a plastic bit on it that prevents it from being plugged in at the same time as the HDMI cable (assuming that's intentional), so I can't try and use that for audio as-is.

I guess my question is: Is buying a SPDIF-to-RCA converter my best bet for getting sound in this situation?

Edit 1: Monitor: SAMSUNG BX2431 LED ([via newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824001440))

Comment: Post your monitor Model.

Comment: Added the model to the post~

Answer (score 4):

You could use something that splits apart the audio and video data sent over the HDMI. something like an [HDMI to RCA Component AV-Converter](http://www.amazon.ca/HDMI-RCA-Component-AV-Converter/dp/B002WBOQPU) with a [HDMI splitter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0015YRMXI) perhaps, or if you have an unlimited budget then one of [these](http://www.gefen.com/kvm/dproduct.jsp?prod_id=8202) should perfectly fit the bill.

Comment: Interesting solution, I had been looking @ this: http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10423&cs_id=1042302&p_id=2948&seq=1&format=2&style. but then I realized it was a "digital" RCA signal which wouldn't work with my mixer

Answer (score 2):

I checked out my monitor some more and there's a single RCA-out connection tucked away on the back of it. I hooked a single rca cord to it, plugged that into a single female-to-dual-male splitter, ran that into my mixer and am able to get slightly-distorted-but-workable stereo sound.

I'm going to try again with a better quality splitter and see if that helps, but its a solution at least.

Comment: You can always run your HDMI cable through a home media reciever, having the HDMI-in, then run audio-out to a speaker system and HDMI-out to the monitor. Alternatively, many monitors have a 3.5mm (standard headphone) jack on them that you can use to output to speakers. I ran my monitor with HDMI video to the monitor and then audio to speakers (or headphones, if I wanted to play without disturbing others).

Answer (score 0):

You need this...
[image: HDMI Audio Adaptor]

If that doesnt work here's a link to the page
https://support.xbox.com/en-AU/xbox-360/connections/connect-sound-system

Go down to Original Xbox system(I know it's not), there is a connector there.
Issue is, you have to buy another HDMI cable with it. It's called a HDMI audio adaptor for Xbox.
Look like you can find them online without the cable though.