# How to use PS3 with a monitor?

Tags: ps3, monitor

My TV was recently stolen, so now I'm hooking the PS3 up to a [Dell monitor 23"](http://www1.ap.dell.com/in/en/home/monitors/monitor-dell-sp2309wfp/pd.aspx?refid=monitor-dell-sp2309wfp&cs=indhs1&s=dhs).  But I have found out it is really difficult to get the sound out of the PS3.

My problem is even if I connect my USB headset, I can't play audio through it, only voice.  There are some turtle beach headphones that work off a special plug on the PS3 (or something) but they cost $150.  Is there a more clever way to get audio out of the PS3?

Comment: Why type of connection are you using to hook the Ps3 to the monitor?

Comment: HDMI, but PS3 recognizes that the monitor has no speaker so can't be used as an audio output.  The monitor has audio jacks on it but Im guessing it can't process the audio signal coming from the ps3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you still have the RCA composite + left/right audio output cable? (The one with the yellow, red and white plugs.) It is possible to configure the PS3 to output audio to both HDMI and the RCA cable.

Under "Settings" go to "Sound Settings" and turn on "Audio Multi-Output".

Comment: +1. This is exactly how I do it too. HDMI for visual and analog for Audio.

Comment: Yeah, I lost that cable but its cheap to replace.  I think this is the best option as well.  It requires a female - female wire to connect headphones to rca though.  This makes it not such a great solution for me.

Comment: It's meant for connecting to an audio receiver of some kind though, not headphones.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a device that separates the HDMI audio and video data with composite outputs, such as i answered in [Help with sound for a Xbox 360 w/ HDMI cable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13624/help-with-sound-for-a-xbox-360-w-hdmi-cable/13628#13628)