# How do I connect non-digital audio to my Xbox 360 S while using HDMI?

Tags: xbox-360

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help with sound for a Xbox 360 w/ HDMI cable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13624/help-with-sound-for-a-xbox-360-w-hdmi-cable)

I just got one of the new Xbox 360 S 4GB models through the Microsoft Intern program. I'd like to "kinect" the 'box to a LCD display which only has DVI input. An $8 cable from Amazon solves that problem. However, the connectors on the 'box now have me puzzled. I don't have fancy speakers that can use the digital audio jack on the Xbox -- I'm driving a Logitech Z-2300 set of speakers, which use a plain jane 1/8" "headphone jack". The speakers came with an RCA cable to headphone jack converter, so I figure it's not a big deal just to use the cable that came with the Xbox and the Amazon cable.

Turns out the cable that came with the Xbox has a little tab that prevents you from plugging in the HDMI cable at the same time. What can I do now?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13624/help-with-sound-for-a-xbox-360-w-hdmi-cable ?

Comment: @badp: Yes, this one is a dupe of that one. The problem in the other question is `The AUX cable that comes with it has the RCA connections on it, but its got a plastic bit on it that prevents it from being plugged in at the same time as the HDMI cable (assuming that's intentional), so I can't try and use that for audio as-is.`, which is exactly my issue here. (That's why I flagged as a dupe)

Comment: Remember you can upvote, or place a bounty, on the original question then :)